# how to make a between clause in addAttributeToFilter?

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes

how to make a between clause in the code like this? I only know less than and greater than ?

```
$_productCollection->addAttributeToFilter('attr_code', array('lteq' => $value)); 

$_productCollection->addAttributeToFilter('attr_code', array('gteq' => $value));
```

Comment: what's the value type you're working with?

Comment: using string .....

Comment: can you provide an example of the values you're trying to match in between

Comment: sorry, it should be int , for example 10000 <> 20000